# Rails user profile page only accessible to correct user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise for the authentication. Right now, I'm setting up user profiles. I have everything set up, except each page is accessible for everyone (so you can see profiles without being logged in). How do I make it so that only the correct user can see their own profile page?

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:show]

  get 'users/show'
```

**show view...**

```
<div class="home-page-content">
  <%= @user.id %>
<h1>Users#show</h1>

<p>Find me in app/views/users/show.html.erb</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may find the https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan gem comes in handy shortly. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325924/7urkm3n answer is the best way for your specific Q though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should help to detect current_user is correct.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :check_user

    private

    def check_user
      if current_user != @user
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, This Profile belongs to someone else !"
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a has_one belongs_to relationship between user and profile. In your controller, you can include some logic that only shows the current user's profile.

Pundit is a nice gem that helps with authorisation - https://github.com/elabs/pundit