# How to delete a has_many :through association plus method authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have an app where users can create groups(cliqs) for others to join. One user owns the group; other users request to join the group. This works through two has_many :through associations (requests/memberships). Everything seems fine as far as group creation and requests. However, I came up against an interesting issue with my membership destroy controller action.

- I need an owner to be able to delete any member from the group
- I need a regular member to not be able to delete any other group member
- I need a current user to be able to delete themselves from the group
- An owner cannot delete their own membership; only the group

**Extra info:** I have a separate controller action for deleting the whole group and it works. I'll use a validation/conditional render to only allow the owner to delete the group.

How should I go about accomplishing these particular stipulations in my controller? How do I show particular options to particular users in the view?

Here are my models:(Shortened for simplicity)

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :owned_cliq, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Cliq', dependent: :destroy

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :cliqs, through: :cliq_memberships
end
```

Cliqs(Groups):

```
class Cliq < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'

has_many :cliq_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :members, through: :cliq_memberships, source: :user
end
```

Here is my controller action:

```
def destroy
    @cliq_membership = current_user.cliq_memberships.find(params[:id])
    @cliq = @cliq_membership.cliq

    @cliq_membership.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "You left the Cliq."
    redirect_to cliqs_path
end
```

And my view:

```
<div>
<% @cliq.members.each do |member| %>
<ul><%= link_to member.username, user_path(member) %></ul>
<% end %>
<% @cliq.cliq_memberships.each do |cliq_membership| %>
(<%= link_to "Delete Member", cliq_membership, :method => :delete %>)
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look at cancan gem it will allow users to access pages/method based on roles. May this resolve the problem. Also this is best practice to not delete the actual records (off course Imp records like group in your case) but add is_deleted flag to indicate whether this group is deleted or not. this is because you may need to refer same group in feature. take a look at soft_delete gem

Comment: Look at this link, close question about current_user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407790/rails-user-profile-page-only-accessible-to-correct-user/36407884#36407884

Comment: That makes sense. Each user will have uploads and I want those to be destroy dependent. The group owns nothing, so I'm not too concerned with soft deleting. I've looked into pundit and that seems like a logical solution to restricting actions. However, my main issue currently is not being able to select a particular user's membership to delete rather than using current_user. My delete action works fine with current_user, but refuses to work when selecting a user(cliq_member). How do I make the method work for user select?