# correct_user without using current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I want people who are not logged in to be able to see the show page. Right now they get a `NoMethodError` error for `current_user`.

```
def show
  @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

**sessions_helper**

```
  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

I use `@correct_user` because I only want to show certain things to the creator of the challenge:

```
<% if @correct_user %>
  # show stuff to user who made challenge  
<% else %>
  # show to everyone else, which would mean logged in users and non logged in users 
<% end %>
```

How can I allow non-logged in users to see the show page, except for what falls within `@correct_user`?

Comment: In the backtrace, what line does the `NoMethodError` appear on?

Comment: look at my answer, also this looks like close question to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407790/rails-user-profile-page-only-accessible-to-correct-user/36407884#36407884

Comment: Clarified question @Trip. It appears for `@correct_user` in the view because `current_user` is nil

Comment: That last `html.erb` bit you have in there `if @correct_user` shold be your answer. It doesn't have to be `if` `else`, it can also be `if !@correct_user` and `if @correct_user`. Could you explain why you're using the word, `correct`? I still don't fully understand what you're up to here

Comment: I think I got it @trip. I added answer below. You were most on track :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if current_user
  @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
else
  @correct_user = nil
end
```

Comment: you could put that into a ternary if you wanted.. just stylistic rewrite `@correct_user = current_user ? current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id]) : nil` . Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 2):

This one should help to detect current_user is correct.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController    
    before_action :set_challenge, only: :show
    before_action :check_user, only: :show

    private 

  def set_ challenge
     @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  end


    def check_user
      if current_user.id != @challenge.user_id
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, You are not allowed to be here, Bye Bye ))"
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Problem is I want non-users to see the show page, but I have a conditional within the view that uses `<% if @correct_user %>` show stuff to user who made challenge  `<% else %>` show to everyone else, which would mean logged in users and non logged in users `<% end %>` Your answer redirects everyone away, which is what I don't want. I'll update question. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.challenges` on `current_user` if `current_user` is `null` will result in your error.

```
def show
  if current_user
    @correct_user = current_user.challenges.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

More than likely `current_user` is returning nil, and therefore the challenges method can't run and gives you `NoMethodError`